# excel getting the range programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, report

I've an excel report to be generated and below is the code that I've used. here I'm hardcoding the range i.e. from A to Z. is there a way to retrieve the Range based on the columns in dataset? Basically I just want to remove the hardcoded values.

```
strCol = String.Empty;
iRow = 0;

foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    iRow++;

    // add each row's cell data...
    iCol = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        iCol++;
        thisWorksheet.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];
        **strCol = "A" + (iRow + 1) + ":Z" + iCol;**
        thisWorksheet.Range[strCol].Borders.Weight = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: sound like there is a way but...please clarify what do you want to replace/retrieve/change and where within your code? As long as it's not complete...

Comment: Suppose in dataset i've columns, now it will fit in A1,B1.. Z1. Now when i add rows to these columns, how will I select the range dynamically and set its cell border = 2. in the code i've hardcoded the range i.e. from A to Z which I dont want to.. Suppose any column is dropped/added in Dataset, i've to change the range in code which is wrong.

Comment: I think there is a tip in @Stefan answer below which you should use. Try to switch from `"A1:B1"` string range reference to `Range(cells(rows, column), cells(row, column))` syntax according to the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

for performance u could put the range in a object[,] and write it back in the end.

```
object[,] orange = range.value;

object[1,1] = "test";

range = orange;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do, but you can get a Range like this:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = null;
Excel.Workbook wkbk;
Excel.Worksheet sheet;

excelApp = new Excel.Application();
wkbk = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
sheet = wkbk.Sheets.Add() as Excel.Worksheet;

Excel.Range c1 = sheet.Cells[Row, Column]; //For instance Cells[1,1] for i think A1
Excel.Range c2 = sheet.Cells[Row, Column];
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)sheet.get_Range(c1,c2);
```